# Implementing a bookmark/flag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a bookmarking feature in my page. Imagine a list of items, each with a flag. You can click on the flag to highlight your selection and click on it again to deselect.

Here, flags is the class of the `div` which holds the icon for the bookmark/flag. I am using the data-flag attribute to keep track of the current state of the bookmark/flag. I am able to change the `data-flag` attribute to `1` whenever I click the flag, but upon clicking it again, instead of resetting the `data-flag` attribute to `0`, it stays as `1` and appends another image in addition to the existing one.

```
$(".flags").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function() {
        var flagtest = $this.data("flag");
            if(flagtest == 0){
                $this.attr("data-flag","1");
                $this.append("<img class='image' src='icon_dark.png'height=8px/>");
            } else if(flagtest == 1){
                $this.attr("data-flag","0");
                $this.append("<img class='image' src='icon_light.png'height=8px/>");
            }
        });
});
```

Can anyone see the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to just use true/false in your data attribute, also you're just appending image after image, you'll have to remove them as well:

```
$(".flags").each(function(idx,elm){
    $(elm).data('flag', false).on('click', function() {
        var flag = $(this).data("flag");
        if (flag) {
            $(this).html("<img class='image' src='icon_dark.png'height=8px/>");
        } else {
            $(this).html("<img class='image' src='icon_light.png'height=8px/>");
        }
        $(this).data("flag", !flag); //toggle state
    });
});​
```

A more neat way is to check if the image exists, and then just change the source if it does:

```
$(".flags").each(function(idx,elm){
    $(elm).data('flag', false).on('click', function() {
        var flag = $(this).data("flag"),
            hasImg = $(this).find('.image').length,
            imgSrc = flag ? 'icon_dark.png' : 'icon_light.png';

        if (hasImg) {
            $('.image', this).attr('src', imgSrc);
        }else{
            var element = $('<img />', {src: imgSrc, 'class':'image', height:'8px'});
            $(this).append(element);
        }

        $(this).data("flag", !flag); //toggle state
    });
});​
```

Comment: I was using integer value since you can sort by the label and the integer values will just group all the selected items together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You are referring to `$this` again in your click handler.
You are also appending to the div rather than changing it.

This is what you want:

```
$(".flags").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function() {
        $this = $(this); // added
        var flagtest = $this.data("flag"); 
            if(flagtest == 0){
                $this.attr("data-flag","1");
                $this.html("<img class='image' src='icon_dark.png'height=8px/>");
            } else if(flagtest == 1){
                $this.attr("data-flag","0");
                $this.html("<img class='image' src='icon_light.png'height=8px/>");
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always append an image tag. You should instead use a class to toggle the style of the image or directly change the `src` property of the `img` tag.

e.g. assuming you are clicking the image itself:

```
<img class='flag' src='icon_dark.png' />

$(".flag").click(function() {
  var img = $(this);

  var flagtest = img.data("flag");
  if (flagtest==0) {
    img.attr('src', 'icon_dark.png');
  } else {        
    img.attr('src', 'icon_light.png');
  }

  img.data("flag", !flagtest);
});
```